# MS Access 2016 can't find my function / module

Tags: ms-access, module, user-defined-functions

I'm still new to VBA, but I'm having an issue trying to automate some function. Namely, I can't seem to be able to run it in immediate (Ctrl+G), and when I try to call it in a Macro, I get the can't find the named function error.

It works when I run the code with no variables, like emailPaste(), and this code is taken from here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

I tried leaving it as emailPaste() and then calling the function in immediate/macro RunCode but still the same issue.

I have named the Module: EmailWithPaste

Current code:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub emailPaste(exFile As String, exSheet As String, EmailSubject As String, _
To_Field As String, Optional CC_Field As String)

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim ApXL As Object

Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ApXL.Workbooks.Open (exFile)


Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets(exSheet).Range("A1:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'If rng Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
       vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    'Exit Sub
'End If

With ApXL.Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Call OpenOutlook
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


With OutMail
    .To = To_Field
    .CC = CC_Field
    .Subject = EmailSubject
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With ApXL.Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        TempWB.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object library? This code requires that. Try adding `Option Explicit` at the top, and then compiling it. Also, this code can't possibly run without parameters, since these aren't optional.

Comment: Yes, I made sure to reference MS Excel Object Library and the Outlok library too. To clarify about the code without parameters, I changed the parameters to be constants, I directly pasted the file path inside the code for example, which is why it worked

Comment: How are you calling it in the immediate window (with parameters)?

Comment: I tired adding Option Explicit at the top, it still can't be found in the Macro

When I try running it in the Immediate, I get the error: Expected Function or variable

? emailPaste("C:\Users\KF\Desktop\TestExcelExport.xlsx","Sheet2","Test","test","cc")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subs are either called without parentheses, or with the deprecated `Call` keyword. Only functions are called with parentheses, hence the *Expected function or variable*.

Also, RunCode runs functions, not subs.

An easy workaround is to change the code to be a function, even though it returns nothing:

```
Public Function emailPaste(exFile As String, exSheet As String, EmailSubject As String, _
To_Field As String, Optional CC_Field As String)
      'The code
End Function
```

And, because it returns nothing, it still should be called as a sub in the immediate window:

```
emailPaste "C:\Users\KF\Desktop\TestExcelExport.xlsx","Sheet2","Test","test","cc"
```